# custom NSTableViewCell

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nstableviewcell

I custom NSTableView just like what I do in UITableView. I implement the datasource and delegate. In the code, I do like this:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    ZJCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier owner:self];
    //this is a custom view
    if (cellView == nil)
    {
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, kTableViewCellHeight);
        cellView = [[[ZJCellView alloc] initWithFrame:NSRectFromCGRect(rect)] autorelease];
        cellView.identifier = cellIdentifier;


      // some other controls

    }
    return cellView;
```

I do the custom just like what I do in iOS. 
The problem is there is a line in both left and right border, like:
[image]

I tried change the frame of the cell view and it seems to be of  no use.
As it is the right way to custom the cell in iOS, I wonder where is it wrong in Cocoa.

Can any body help me?
thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I find it is the `Cell Space` which can be set in the nib.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS:

Tableviewcells have same with with Tableview. They are autoresized. If you set frame for a cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, changes nothing.

For width you need to change the width of the tableview.
For height you need to implement delegate method heightForRowAtIndexPath: of the tableview or set rowHeight property.

But I don't know how is it for NSTableView, I think it is similar.

Comment: I have already initialed the cell view with the tableview's width. The problem exists.